# RESTful web services in C# to produce or consume both JSON and XML objects

Tags: c#, web-services, rest

Please anyone suggest me a link or website for Creating RESTFul Web Services in C# which should be able to consume and produce both XML and JSON object. Application should respond with requested type of object sent in http request header.

Thanks In advance for all replies.

Comment: You could look at MVC [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ASP.Net Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) is the thing you are looking for.

Also [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx) can help you.